# What is the algorithmic complexity of the code below

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, big-o

Is the Big-O for the following code O(n) or O(log n)?

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i*=2)
        sum++;
```

It looks like O(n) or am I missing this completely?

Comment: Why does this look like O(n) to you?

Comment: Thanks all for explaining this it is much appreciated. I am new to this but definetly can now see why it has to be O(log n).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is `O(logn)`, since `i` is doubled each time. So at overall you need to iterate `k` times, until `2^k = n`, and in this case it happens when `k = logn` (since `2^logn = n`).

Simple example: Assume `n = 100` - then:

```
iter1: i = 1
iter2: i = 2
iter3: i = 4
iter4: i = 8
iter5: i = 16
iter6: i = 32
iter7: i = 64
iter8: i = 128 > 100
```

It is easy to see that an iteration will be added when `n` is doubled, which is logarithmic behavior, while linear behavior is adding iterations for a constant increase of `n`.

**P.S. (EDIT):** *mathematically speaking*, the algorithm is indeed `O(n)` - since big-O notation gives *asymptotic upper bound*, and your algorithm runs asymptotically "faster" then `O(n)` - so it is indeed `O(n)` - but it is not a tight bound (It is not `Theta(n)`) and I doubt that is actually what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The complexity is **O(logn)** because the loops runs (log<sub>2</sub>n - 1) times.

Answer (score 2):

O(log(n)), as you only loop ~log2(n) times

Answer (score 1):

No the complexity is not linear. Try to play through a few scenarios: how many iterations does this cycle do for n = 2, n=4, n=16, n=1024? How about for n = 1024 * 1024? Maybe this will help you get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

For loop check runs lg(n) +1 times. The inner loop runs lg(n) times. So, the complexity is is O(lg n), not O(log n).

If n==8, the following is how the code will run:

1. i=1
2. i=2
3. i=4
4. i=8 --Exit condition

Comment: There's no difference between O(lg n) and O(log n).

Comment: To explain @TedHopp's comment I'll add: `log_k(n) = log_m(n)/log_m(k)`. In this case: `log(n) = lg(n)/lg(10)`. Since `lg(10)` is constant, under big-O notation, `O(log(n)) = O(lg(n))`

Answer (score 0):

It is O(log(n)).
Look at the  code num++; 
It loops O(log(n)) times.